# How Could I Optimize My Breadth Search Algorithm For Solving Bigger Mazes

Tags: c, optimization, breadth-first-search, maze

I'm working on a project where I need to solve a maze, and prints the solution on the standart output:

From this:
[image: example of maze unsolved]

To this:
[image: Maze Solved]

To do so, I used the A* (astar) algorithm, without the cost problem, cause I don't care about finding the shortest path since the maze is solved. So I just have two linked list, which contains nodes which are the positions on the map.

Anyway, it is now working, but I want to improve my times on bigger mazes, cause it takes more than 10 seconds on 500x500 mazes, and more than a whole minute on 1000x1000 mazes, I already did few things, such as optimizing my add_node function, or the call of in_list function which search if a node is already on closed list, but, even if It had doubled or trippled the speed, this is clearly not enough A* algorithm should be way faster.

Here is my implementation of the program in C:

````
//my header's structures:
typedef struct node_s
{
    int x;
    int y;
} node_t;

typedef struct maze_s
{
    char **map;
    int dim[2];
    node_t start;
    node_t objective;
    node_t *current;
    bool states[4];
} maze_t;

typedef struct linked_list_s
{
    node_t node;
    node_t *parent;
    struct linked_list_s *next;
} linked_list_t;```

//And here The Most Important Utils Functions:
void in_closed(linked_list_t *closed_list, maze_t *maze)
{
    linked_list_t *tmp = closed_list;
    node_t *crt = maze->current;

    if (!tmp)
        return;
    while (tmp) {
        if (tmp->node.x == crt->x + 1 && tmp->node.y == crt->y) {
            maze->states[0] = true;
        }
        if (tmp->node.x == crt->x && tmp->node.y == crt->y + 1) {
            maze->states[1] = true;
        }
        if (tmp->node.x == crt->x && tmp->node.y == crt->y - 1) {
            maze->states[2] = true;
        }
        if (tmp->node.x == crt->x - 1 && tmp->node.y == crt->y) {
            maze->states[3] = true;
        }
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}

linked_list_t *add_node(linked_list_t *list, node_t node, node_t *parent)
{
    linked_list_t *new = malloc(sizeof(linked_list_t));

    new->node = node;
    new->parent = parent;
    new->next = list;
    return (new);
}

linked_list_t *remove_node(linked_list_t *list, node_t *node)
{
    linked_list_t *head = list;

    if (list->node.x == node->x && list->node.y == node->y) {
        list = list->next;
        return (list);
    }
    while (list->next) {
        if (list->next->node.x == node->x && list->next->node.y == node->y) {
            list->next = list->next->next;
            return (head);
        } else {
            list = list->next;
        }
    }
    return (NULL);
}

//And then the main algorithm (all the functions that I didn't show were not important for my problem) :

linked_list_t *check_neighbour(int neighbour, maze_t *maze,
                    linked_list_t *list, linked_list_t *closed_list)
{
    node_t *crt = maze->current;

    if (neighbour == 1 && crt->x + 1 < maze->dim[0] && !maze->states[0]
        && maze->map[crt->x + 1][crt->y] == '*') {
        list = add_node(list, (node_t){crt->x + 1, crt->y}, crt);
    }
    if (neighbour == 2 && crt->y + 1 < maze->dim[1] && !maze->states[1]
        && maze->map[crt->x][crt->y + 1] == '*') {
        list = add_node(list, (node_t){crt->x, crt->y + 1}, crt);
    }
    if (neighbour == 0 && crt->y > 0 && !maze->states[2]
        && maze->map[crt->x][crt->y - 1] == '*') {
        list = add_node(list, (node_t){crt->x, crt->y - 1}, crt);
    }
    if (neighbour == 3 && crt->x > 0 && !maze->states[3]
        && maze->map[crt->x - 1][crt->y] == '*') {
        list = add_node(list, (node_t){crt->x - 1, crt->y}, crt);
    }
    return (list);
}

void end(maze_t *maze, linked_list_t *closed_list)
{
    linked_list_t *tmp = closed_list;
    bool cond = true;

    for (int x = maze->objective.x, y = maze->objective.y; tmp->next;) {
        if (tmp->node.x == x && tmp->node.y == y) {
            maze->map[x][y] = 'o';
            x = tmp->parent->x;
            y = tmp->parent->y;
            closed_list = remove_node(closed_list, &tmp->node);
            tmp = closed_list;
            cond = false;
        }
        if (cond) {
            tmp = tmp->next;
        } else {
            cond = true;
        }
    }
    maze->map[0][0] = 'o';
}

linked_list_t *solve_maze(maze_t *maze, linked_list_t *list,
                                linked_list_t *closed_list)
{
    while (list) {
        if (list->node.x == maze->objective.x
            && list->node.y == maze->objective.y)
            return (closed_list);
        maze->current = &list->node;
        closed_list = add_node(closed_list, list->node, list->parent);
        in_closed(closed_list, maze);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            list = check_neighbour(i, maze, list, closed_list);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            maze->states[i] = false;
        list = remove_node(list, maze->current);
    }
    return(NULL);
}

int solver(char **av)
{
    int *dim = get_dimensions(av[1]);
    maze_t maze = {.dim = {dim[0], dim[1]}, .map = get_map(av[1], dim),
        .start = {0, 0}, .objective = {dim[0] - 1, dim[1] - 1}, .states =
        {false, false, false, false}};
    linked_list_t *list = get_open_list(&maze);
    linked_list_t *closed_list = NULL;

    if (maze.map[0][0] == 'X' || maze.map[dim[0] - 1][dim[1] - 1] == 'X')
        return (printf("no solution found\n"));
    closed_list = solve_maze(&maze, list, closed_list);
    if (!closed_list)
        return (printf("no solution found\n"));
    closed_list = add_node(closed_list, maze.objective, &closed_list->node);
    printf("algorithm done\n");
    end(&maze, closed_list);
    printf("end finished\n");
    print_map_color(&maze);
    return (0);
}
````

Comment: If you delete the cost part of A* then you don't have A* any more, you have Depth-First Search.

Comment: I changed the title then

Comment: That main problem with your code is that you used a list for the visited set.  You should use an Boolean array with a slot for each vertex, false for unvisited and true for visited.  Also the code is way more complicated than necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your entire goal here is just to solve the maze once, then A* is completely overkill. The main virtue of A* is that a lot of the time you don't need to look at a bunch of the spaces on the maze. In this case, you are reading the entire maze into memory anyway (plus your maze is only ~10^6 squares in size, which is fairly small). *If you have to read the entire grid into memory anyway, your solution is going to be O(n) bestcase* where *n* is the number of spaces in the grid. From the looks of it, you have made some extremely complicated code that is probably O(n^2) or O(pathLength * n) worst case.

You should be able to use just BFS. The code below is in Java and runs in O(n).

Here's the output of my solution on a 10 by 10 case:

```
Possible
oX********
ooo*X***X*
**oX****X*
XXoX**X**X
X*ooX*****
*X*ooooooX
****X***oX
*****X**oo
*X***X***o
*****X***o
1
```

Here's the code in Java:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Random;

public class BFS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int w=1000, h=1000;
        long time=System.currentTimeMillis();
        Random r=new Random();
        char[][] board=new char[w][h];
        for (int x=0; x<w; x++)
            for (int y=0; y<h; y++) 
                board[x][y]=r.nextInt(5)<1?'X':'*';

        int[] dx= {1, 0, -1, 0};
        int[] dy= {0, -1, 0, 1};
        int[][] cameFrom=new int[w][h];
        boolean[][] visited=new boolean[w][h];
        Queue<Integer> xs=new LinkedList<>(), ys=new LinkedList<>();
        xs.add(0);
        ys.add(0);
        cameFrom[0][0]=-1;
        visited[0][0]=true;
        while (!xs.isEmpty()) {
            int fromX=xs.remove(), fromY=ys.remove();
            for (int d=0; d<4; d++) {
                int nx=fromX+dx[d], ny=fromY+dy[d];
                if (nx<0||ny<0||nx>=w||ny>=h||visited[nx][ny]||board[nx][ny]=='X') continue;
                visited[nx][ny]=true;
                cameFrom[nx][ny]=d;
                xs.add(nx);
                ys.add(ny);
            }
        }
        PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(System.out);
        if (!visited[w-1][h-1]) {
            out.println("Impossible...");
        }
        else {
            out.println("Possible");
            int x=w-1, y=h-1;
            while (cameFrom[x][y]!=-1) {
                board[x][y]='o';
                int d=cameFrom[x][y];
                x-=dx[d];
                y-=dy[d];
            }
            for (y=0; y<h; y++) {
                for (x=0; x<w; x++) out.print(board[x][y]);
                out.println();
            }
        }
        out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()-time);
        out.close();
    }

}
```

This runs in under 0.6 seconds for a 1000 by 1000 grid, and most of that time is spent printing the output grid. It also always finds the shortest path since the graph is unweighted.

Comment: Thank you, after reproducing your bfs algorithm in C, optimizing the variable declaration to not recreate each time an int in the loop, the times are amazing, it is nearly 0.13 seconds for a 1000 by 1000 grid, and the algorithm takes 3.5 secondes for 10000*10000 grids, it is not printing the shortest path though, but it doesn't matter anyway.